# pulling out her hair

Tags: behavior

I have a 4 y/o,  pomeranian /shi-tzu/yorkshire mix female.  She is fixed.  Over the past year, she has episodes of pulling her hair out on her back.  I've changed food, for higher omegas, switched to oatmeal shampoo, used the 8 month flea collar, had a complete check up, including blood panel to rule out thyroid issues. Everything came back great.  The vet put her on a very expensive anti itch pill.  Nothing really works.  It helps some, but doesn't stop the problem. Does anyone have any ideas.  She's definitely not under any stress.  I'm destroying my aloe vera plant trying to soothe her skin.
Thanks

Comment: Do you use a dry-powder carpet cleaner/freshener? These caused severe pruritus for one of our dogs. The pruritus resolved very quickly, once we stopped using it, and gave the carpets a good shampooing.

Comment: Welcome to Pets StackExchange! It looks like there's a duplicate of your question already. There are a few answers there but if you find none of them help, you can update your own question explaining how it is different to the duplicate question.